# Python PyGtk virtual keyboard support with at-spi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, accessibility, pygtk, raspberry-pi3

I wrote a PyGtk app to control some specific functionality on a Pi3. This full screen GUI (via a 2.8" TFT touch screen) is all the user has to interact with the device. There is no mouse, keyboard, SSH, VNC, etc available. Because there is a requirement to get input from the user I need to implement a way to have a virtual keyboard appear when a text box gets focus and then disappear when focus is lost. I researched a number of virtual keyboards and the only one that seems to offer this functionality with Gtk support is Florence. But I cannot get it to automatically show/hide when an input text box gets/loses focus.

Florence relies on the at-spi framework to get event notifications. According to "Florence modes" (http://florence.sourceforge.net/english/usage.html)

```
You should make sure your applications support at-spi if you intend to use Florence in hidden mode.
```

and

```
The auto hide mode requires accessibility to be activated, which means the at-spi registry daemon is running and applications are using it.
```

Also, according to the FAQ (http://florence.sourceforge.net/english/how-to.html) an environment variable needs to be set.

```
export GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
```

So I configured Florence for auto-hide mode, downloaded at-spi, ran the registry daemon and set the environment variable but no dice. When a text box on the GUI is focused, the keyboard does not appear.

I suppose I have two questions.  First, I am not tied to Florence by any means so if there is another solution I am open to implementing it.  But second, one thing that is not clear to me is how I can make the PyGtk app "support at-spi."  Other than the environment variable how do I make sure my app uses at-spi?  None of the documentation is clear to me on that point.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a raspberry pi (RPi) yet, so this answer might not work on RPi.

It does work on linux, so you might want to test it on RPi.

I installed `OnBoard` (another virtual keyboard that supports DBus).

Make sure that you OnBoard running but with the virtual keyboard hidden.

The following code will control the visibility of the virtual keyboard:

```
import dbus

# initialize session bus, you can put the following lines into 
# your initialization block, or something or use a class
sess_bus = dbus.SessionBus()

# get the object proxy for the virtual keyboard, 
# won't work if OnBoard is not already running
kbd = sess_buss.get_object('org.onboard.Onboard', 
                           '/org/onboard/Onboard/Keyboard')


# display virtual keyboard
kbd.Show()

# hide virtual keyboard
kbd.Hide()
```